# Windows 10 GPO auto shutdown when idle on login screen

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-10, windows-server-2008, group-policy

Is it possible to make computers shutdown (with task scheduler or a script) via GPO when there are no users logged in?.

What i have now is that users are being logged off automatically, when they are inactive for 1 hour after 18:00 after that i want the computer to shutdown automatically for the night.

Is this possible even when there are no users logged in?

Answer (score 0):

It works now, forgot to add the computers inside the OU. After that the sheduled task was created on the machines and they now auto shutdown at a certain time